# previous URL document.referrer is empty

Tags: javascript, referrer

I have saved link on this page: https://sites.google.com/site/sanccvfx/home

http://127.0.0.1:5000 and http://192.168.1.2:5000

but when I capture using `document.referrer` the come out to be empty string instead of from where they are coming.

Comment: changing from https to http will drop the referrer, it's a security measure. Here is [a link for further reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer#Referer_hiding)

Comment: Plus, websites these days have multiple ways of specifying what value - if any - is send, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy